# How to create slot picker(Minute/Hour) in Android?

Tags: android, picker

I want to create the time slot picker dialog as per the given image below:

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how can I achieve this? We have Date and Time Picker, but we doesn't have this type of native slot picker in Android. Thanks

Comment: You can try this Library[https://github.com/gzu-liyujiang/AndroidPicker](https://github.com/gzu-liyujiang/AndroidPicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use control ***NumberPicker***

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker_hour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden" />

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker_min"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can make the above time slot picker using Spinner in android.

Or you can use some open source libraries which provides you the boiler code.

[Open source libraries for time picker](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27)